# Choosing Redis datatypes for advanced data manipulation in a simple torrent tracker service

Tags: ruby, redis

I need your advice on Redis datatypes for my project. The project is a torrent-tracker (`ruby`, simple `sinatra-based`) with pure in-memory data store for current information about peers. I feel like this is what Redis is made for. But I'm stuck at choosing proper data types for this. For now I tend to the following setup:

1. Use `list` for seeders. Actually I'd better need a ring buffer to get a sequential range of seeders (with given size and start position) and save new start position for the next time.
2. Use `sorted set` for leechers. Score for each leecher is `downloaded/(downloaded+left)` so I can also extract a range for any specific case.

All string values in set and list are string (bencoded) representation of peer data.

What I actually lack in the setup above is:

1. Necessity to store offset for seeders so data access needs synchronization.
2. Unknown method of finding a specific seeder in list. Here I may benefit from `set` but then I won't be able to extract a range of items at once.
3. (General problem) Need TTL for set/list members (if client shuts down without sending any data before this). Possible option is to make each `peer` an ordinary string key/value (string or hash), give it TTL, subscribe on destroy and delete it in corresponding list or set.

What could you suggest? Any practical advice?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're wanting to do. What does this mean: "Necessity to store offset for seeders"? Also, do you need to perform any additional logic when the TTL expires, or do you just want the data to disapear?

Comment: @ABentSpoon Look, I have a list of 20 elements. I take first 8 (0-7). Next time I'll take elements 8-15, next = 16-3 ... This is what I mean by offset.  
And about TTL - just remove this values. In a list I just can't query for value. I'm thinking about a sorted set also.  
Another option for me was to organize directed graphs, but this will require lots of memory usage even for a hundred peers.